Bicep adding DNS Records saying already exists when it doesn't
I am using Bicep to deploy our applications infrastructure and we're trying to add our SendGrid Domain Authentication DNS Records into the Bicep so we can deploy across our different environments, or a new environment if we choose, replace the values in the parameters.{environment}.json file and run it.
We're deploying our environment through GitHub's Actions and so far, up until this point, no problem has occurred that has left me feeling stuck until now - our domain registrar is another party but our NS have been changed to Azure so we're managing the whole platform through Azure.
resource dnsZonesNameResouce 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones@2023-07-01-preview' existing = {
  name: dnsZonesName
}

The DNS Zone name is passed in as a parameter into the module.
Here's an example of creating a DNS Record further down utilising this resource as it's parent
resource dnsZoneSendGridS1 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME@2023-07-01-preview' = {
  parent: dnsZonesNameResouce 
  name: sendGridS1Name
  properties: {
    TTL: 3600
    TXTRecords: [
      {
        value: [
          sendGridS1Value
        ]
      }
    ]
    targetResource: {}
  }
}

All of these parameters are passed in, the important thing is none of these records exist on the domain I am attempting to assign them to, when it comes to running this Bicep in the relevant GitHub Action, I always receive multiple errors, all of them following the same format
"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/rg-common/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/some.domain.com/CNAME/em3203.some.domain.com","message":"***\r\n  \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n  \"message\": \"Resource records can contain only one type of record specified.
This error is repeated multiple times for each different DNS Record I am trying to insert from this module I have given a snippet of above, these records do NOT exist in the domain on Azure which I am absolutely certain of, yet, the Bicep insists that it does.
Running what-if shows a result that looks like exactly what I need it to run against our environment, however, when we actually run it this error appears
Any help is appreciated!
I have tried changing the resource@... version to see if there is a mismatch, which hasn't yielded any results
Running what-if shows what I would expect to be correct from the Bicep I have written

if it is CNAME record you should use the CNAMERecord property right? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/dnszones/cname?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#cnamerecord

If your post you are using the TXTRecords property which is for TXT record? Sorry I'm not too familiar with Azure DNS so ignore if irrelevant

@Thomas checking Microsoft DNS CNAME it doesn't mention CNAMERecord it just says CNAME - I will give it a go though as there's no harm in trying!

@Thomas unfortunately CNAMERecord didn't work

same error or different ?

The error changes, there's now two, the first error is: Warning BCP081: Resource type "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAMERecord@2023-07-01-preview" does not have types available. Bicep is unable to validate resource properties prior to deployment, but this will not block the resource from being deployed and the second error is: The client '{clientId}' with object id '{objectId}' does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAMERecord/write' at scope '{subscriptionId}'

the error looks better tbh

its saying that you dont have permission to update the dns zone.

so i assume once you fix that it should work

Hopefully! Just trying to sort out the permission stuff for it and I'll let you know if it does work and you can post your solution and I'll mark it as the answer

May be youre missing this "DNS Zone Contributor" role permission @Tom


Bicep adding DNS Records saying already exists when it doesn't

The blocker you mentioned in the comments Resource type "Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAMERecord@2023-07-01-preview" does not have types available because of inability of bicep not to validate the properties before deployment & the second error is due missing permission of role DNS Zone Contributor which need to assigned to your SP or user.
I also agreed with Thomas on the point he mentioned related to how we use TXTRecords in the bicep configuration.
main.bicep:
param dnsZonesName string
param sendGridS1Name string
param sendGridS1Value string


resource dnsZonesNameResouce 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones@2023-07-01-preview' existing = {
  name: dnsZonesName
}


resource dnsZoneSendGridS1 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/CNAME@2023-07-01-preview' = {
  parent: dnsZonesNameResouce 
  name: sendGridS1Name
  properties: {
    TTL: 3600
    CNAMERecord: {
      cname: sendGridS1Value
    }
  }
}

parameters.json:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "dnsZonesName": {
        "value": "vkdomain.com"
      },
      "sendGridS1Name": {
        "value": "em3203.vkdomain.com"
      },
      "sendGridS1Value": {
        "value": "sendgrid.net"
      }
    }
  }

I have a preexisting DNS record created vkdomain.com

Deployment succedded:


Reference:
Microsoft.Network/dnsZones - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn

That's a fair point and you were right with the CNAMERecord
